# Dynamically created jagged rectangular array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

In my project I have a lot of code like this:

```
int[][] a = new int[firstDimension][];
for (int i=0; i<firstDimension; i++)
{
  a[i] = new int[secondDimension];
}
```

Types of elements are different.

Is there any way of writing a method like

```
createArray(typeof(int), firstDimension, secondDimension);
```

and getting `new int[firstDimension][secondDimension]`?

Once again, type of elements is known only at runtime.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generics should do the trick:

```
static T[][] CreateArray<T>(int rows, int cols)
{
    T[][] array = new T[rows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        array[i] = new T[cols];

    return array;
}
```

You do have to specify the type when calling this:

```
char[][] data = CreateArray<char>(10, 20);
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a big help for me, but that would require a huge refactoring in an existing project.

After initializing, arrays are used only as jagged arrays.

Comment: Can you explain the refactoring? I edited out the 'var', but that was just notation.

Comment: OK, I misread the 'at runtime'. That would mean @pete has a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do this:

```
int[,] array = new int[4,2];
```

What you get is called a multidimensional array (4x2). [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4(VS.71).aspx) is a nice article about multidimensional arrays.

The term jagged array usually refers to arrays, that have different second dimensions. For example take:

```
int[][] jagged = new int[2][];
jagged[0] = new int[5]; // 5 elements
jagged[1] = new int[1]; // 1 element
```

so this is not a 2x5 array, but a jagged array..

Comment: That would be too easy :)
But I need to use the second dimensions as an arrays, for example: int[] a = array[3], which I can not do with multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

If:

- You definitely want a jagged array, and not a multi-dimensional one as mOsa mentions.
- You definitely need it to be of dynamic type at runtime, and not at compile time using generics as Henk mentions.

You can use [Array.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx) something like:

```
static Array CreateArray (Type t, int rows, int cols)
{

    Array arr = Array.CreateInstance (typeof(Array), rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; rows++) {
        arr.SetValue (Array.CreateInstance(t, cols), i);
    }

    return arr;
}
```

But are you *sure* you need this to by dynamic type at runtime?

Comment: Thanks, tried this too. By the way, there is an error - should be 'Array arr = Array.CreateInstance (Array, rows)' I think :)

The problem was that i couldn't refer to elements like arr[i][k] then. Casting to type[][] didn't work too.

Actually, you're right, I can forgot about dynamic types and use generics.

Comment: the for loop is incrementing 'rows, not 'i ... afaik: you will not be able to cast the created Array returned by this into any other form of Array.

Answer (score -1):

As mOsa mentioned, if you want rectangular jagged array, then you are better off using a multi-dimensional array.

```
int[,] array = new int[dimension, dimension2];
```

will generate a rectangular array.

The reason to use a jagged array, is if you want to create an array with different secondary dimensions. A jagged array is really an array of arrays, where as a multi-dimensional array is a slightly different beast.

Comment: Huh, that I didn't know. That doesn't surprise me though.